# Empty files can't be valid archives when running sudo apt update

Tags: apt, software-installation, updates, update-manager

I have just make a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04.
I've never seen this error on ubuntu 15.10.
When I try to run `sudo apt update`:

```
Hit:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                                                                       
Get:2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [82,2 kB]                           
Ign:5 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily InRelease                                   
Hit:6 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily Release                                     
Get:4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [82,2 kB]
Hit:8 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit:9 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit:10 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en
Hit:11 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit:12 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit:13 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit:14 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit:15 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit:16 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit:17 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en    
Ign:11 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign:14 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign:17 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit:18 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit:19 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:18 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit:8 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit:9 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit:10 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en
Hit:11 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit:12 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit:13 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign:9 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en
Ign:11 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit:14 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit:15 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit:16 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit:17 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign:17 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit:20 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit:21 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit:22 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main Translation-en
Hit:23 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:20 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:21 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
Ign:22 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main Translation-en
Ign:23 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit:24 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit:25 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted Translation-en
Ign:24 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:25 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit:26 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit:27 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit:28 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Translation-en
Hit:29 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:26 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:27 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:28 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign:29 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit:30 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit:31 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit:18 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit:19 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Err:8 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
  Empty files can't be valid archives
Err:9 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
  Empty files can't be valid archives
Ign:30 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:31 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit:10 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en
Err:11 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
  Empty files can't be valid archives
Err:10 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en
  Empty files can't be valid archives
Err:12 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  Empty files can't be valid archives
Hit:13 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en
Err:13 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en
  Empty files can't be valid archives
Err:14 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  Empty files can't be valid archives
Err:15 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
  Empty files can't be valid archives
Hit:16 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en
Err:16 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en
  Empty files can't be valid archives
Err:17 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Empty files can't be valid archives
Hit:20 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit:21 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
Ign:20 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:21 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit:22 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main Translation-en
Hit:23 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit:24 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:22 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main Translation-en
Ign:23 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:24 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit:25 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted Translation-en
Ign:25 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit:26 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit:27 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit:28 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Translation-en
Hit:29 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:26 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:27 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:28 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign:29 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit:30 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit:31 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:30 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:31 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Err:20 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
  Empty files can't be valid archives
Err:21 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
  Empty files can't be valid archives
Hit:22 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main Translation-en
Err:23 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
  Empty files can't be valid archives
Err:22 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main Translation-en
  Empty files can't be valid archives
Err:24 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  Empty files can't be valid archives
Hit:25 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted Translation-en
Err:26 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages
  Empty files can't be valid archives
Err:27 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages
  Empty files can't be valid archives
Hit:28 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Translation-en
Err:25 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted Translation-en
  Empty files can't be valid archives
Err:28 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Translation-en
  Empty files can't be valid archives
Err:29 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Empty files can't be valid archives
Err:30 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  Empty files can't be valid archives
Fetched 164 kB in 2s (68,0 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/Release.gpg: Signature by key 1C61A2656FB57B7E4DE0F4C1FC918B335044912E uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Empty files can't be valid archives
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  Empty files can't be valid archives
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/fr.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en  Empty files can't be valid archives
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Empty files can't be valid archives
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Empty files can't be valid archives
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/fr.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_restricted_i18n_Translation-en  Empty files can't be valid archives
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Empty files can't be valid archives
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Empty files can't be valid archives
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/fr.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_universe_i18n_Translation-en  Empty files can't be valid archives
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Empty files can't be valid archives
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Empty files can't be valid archives
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  Empty files can't be valid archives
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/fr.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_i18n_Translation-en  Empty files can't be valid archives
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Empty files can't be valid archives
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Empty files can't be valid archives
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/fr.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_restricted_i18n_Translation-en  Empty files can't be valid archives
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Empty files can't be valid archives
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Empty files can't be valid archives
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/fr.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_universe_i18n_Translation-en  Empty files can't be valid archives
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Empty files can't be valid archives
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Empty files can't be valid archives
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

It's just a fresh install I have just install Dropbox (I had already the issue at the very begining.

Edit:
In Setting -> software & update -> I have set `Download from france` to `download from main server`.

Now when I run `sudo apt update` I have this output:

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                             
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]                       
Ign:5 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily InRelease                
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease         
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease        
Hit:8 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily Release                       
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Fetched 247 kB in 1s (196 kB/s)                    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

So now it works but I have only 8 lines. Is that normal?